# CiviEvent detailed schedule

Tags: civievent

When creating multi-day events, I'd like to display a more detailed schedule than what's shown by the "When" field. The "When" field essentially shows the duration of the event, but I'd also like to have a "Schedule" field to show the days and times of the week. Is something this possible?

```
When      March 1st, 2016 7:00 PM   through   May 26th, 2016 9:30 PM
Schedule  Mondays 7:00 - 9:30 PM
          Wednesdays 7:00 - 9:00 PM 
Location  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a custom field for the event (not the participants, but the event itself) such that you could input a schedule as needed.  More details here: http://book.civicrm.org/user/events/setup/